# sudo unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain

Tags: 12.04, ftp

Hello guys

When I run

`sudo nano /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`

I get this error :

`sudo unable to resolve host localhost.localdomain`

I'm trying to set `DefaultRoot` to `/var/www`as per the following screenshots.

[image: nano_screenshot]

When I press <kbd>CTRl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then write <kbd>Y</kbd> and press enter,/kbd> it give me this error

[image: errors_screenshot]

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: what does /etc/hosts contains ?

Comment: Please explain , did you mean my pc (windows 7) or on ths server because i'am running propdf on ubuntu 12.0.4 vps

Comment: Hello sir , it contains

Comment: `127.0.0.1       localhost`
`127.0.1.1       ubuntu12.pcsmarthosting.co.uk   ubuntu12`

                                                                `# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`
@nux

Answer (score 12):

Edit your server hosts file (`/etc/hosts`).  You are missing the domain.  For example:

It probably has a line like:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Change it to:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain  localhost
```